# Is there an efficient way to show images based on a route and file name using javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Right now I have something like

```
const route = '/Images/Banner/'
const slides = [
  {
      name: "banner-01",
      url: `${route}banner-01.png`
  },
  {
      name: "banner-02",
      url: `${route}banner-02.png`
 
  },
  {
      name: "banner-03",
      url: `${route}banner-03.png`
  },
]
]
```

In this, I'm manually adding each image and it's properties because there are only 3 images, but i want to dynamically add them based on the quantity of images with the same name (they'll always are going to be named banner-NN).

Is there an efficient way to iterate through images with the same pattern of name ('banner-') and place them in an array of objects?

Comment: Create an array and map over it to create the objects?

Answer (score 3):

Iterating over the indicies of a collection and then inserting the indicies into the strings is easy enough...

```js
const route = '/Images/Banner/'
const slides = Array.from(
  { length: 3 }, // 1 to 3
  (_, i) => {
    const numStr = String(i + 1).padStart(2, '0');
    return {
      name: `banner-${numStr}`,
      url: `${route}banner-${numStr}`,
    };
  }
);
console.log(slides);
```

Answer (score 1):

@CertainPerformance's answer is fine but it relies on Array.from which not all browsers support. Just putting my way of doing this out there

```js
const route = "/Images/Banner/";
const slides = [];
const totalItems = 100;

for (let index = 0; index < totalItems; index++) {
  const banner = `banner-${index.toString().length > 1 ? index : `0${index}`}`;

  slides.push({
    name: banner,
    url: `${route}${banner}.png`,
  });
}

console.log(slides);
```

Comment: `Array.from` isn't supported on IE, which end of life is june 2022. And since this question is tagged React, it's possible to configure polyfills to support older browsers so that you don't have to code with these limitations in mind.

Comment: 93% of users have Array.from support [source](https://caniuse.com/?search=Array.from) I was shocked by this too.